# Access Google SQL instance while creating backup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have an instance running a database on the Google Cloud Platform (MySQL Second Generation master). It is currently taking a backup of the database, and has been doing so for more than 13 hours!

When I try to log into my database through my terminal, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) HTTPError 409: Operation failed because another operation was already in progress.
```

Any idea why it has taken so many hours to create a backup? Anything I can do to be able to view my database in the meantime?

All help is welcome - thank you!

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901 ...the project number and Cloud SQL instance name are required when filing an such "private" issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm with GCP Support. Since this question can't be answered without inspecting your project and metrics, I suggest you to either open a technical support case if you have technical support or raise your issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901) with your project number and Cloud SQL instance as mentioned by Martin. If you decide for the last one, please provide the link.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. The backup of my database was finished when I checked again today. I agree my question was very specific to my case, but is there a way to log in to the database (even for readonly) while creating backup?

Comment: While there is a backup in progress you can not log in the instance. The best way to access the data (readonly) is to [set up a read replica](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica) which you will be able to access even while a backup of master instance is in progress.

Comment: I understand, good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why it has taken so many hours to create a backup?

This question can't be answered without inspecting your project and metrics, I suggest you to either open a technical support case if you have technical support or raise your issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901) with your project number and Cloud SQL instance

> Anything I can do to be able to view my database in the meantime?

While there is a backup in progress you can not log in the instance. The best way to access the data (readonly) is to set up a read replica which you will be able to access even while a backup of master instance is in progress.